# A regex with Splunk

Tags: regex, splunk

Got some troubles with my regex.

I got some lines like this:

```
SomeText#"C:\\","Shadow Copy Components:\\","E:\\",""
SomeText#"D:\\"
SomeText#"E:\\","Shadow Copy Components:\\"
SomeText#"SET SNAP_ID=serv.a.x.com_1380312019","BACKUP H:\\ USING \\\\?\\GLOBALROOT\\Device\\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy47\\ OPTIONS:ALT_PATH_PREFIX=c:\\VERITAS\\NetBackup\\temp\\_vrts_frzn_img_3200\"
SomeText#"SET SNAP_ID=serv.a.x.com_1380312019","BACKUP Y:\\Libs USING \\\\?\\GLOBALROOT\\Device\\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy47\\ OPTIONS:ALT_PATH_PREFIX=c:\\VERITAS\\NetBackup\\temp\\_vrts_frzn_img_3200\"
```

What i would like is to get a group named jobFileList containing for each line:

```
"C:\\","Shadow Copy Components:\\","E:\\",""
"D:\\"
"E:\\","Shadow Copy Components:\\"
H:\\
Y:\\Libs
```

You can see i only want the file list, but some times its only the full text after the # mark and sometimes there is a lot of **** that i need to remove.
Fact is i cant use a script for this case so i need to do this with only ONE regexp, can't just do a streplace of other stuff after the regex.

What i did is :

```
SomeText(#.*BACKUP (?P<jobFileList>.*?) .*)?(#(?P<jobFileList>.*))?
```

But seems i cant set the same GroupName :( If i replace the second jobFileList with another name its works perfectly but not what i need .

Thanks for your help,

EDIT:
I can also have some lines like :

```
SomeText#/ahol5d72_1_2
SomeText#/p7ol4a1p_1_2
SomeText#Gvadag04SANDsk_Daily
SomeText#/bck_reco_a9ol5765_1_2_827497669
```

In all these cases i need to have all the text after the # mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A version which doesn't rely on the double quotes after the double backslash:

```
SomeText#(?:(.*?BACKUP) )?(?P<jobFileList>(?(1)[^ ]*|.*$))
```

This: `(?(1)[^ ]*|.*$)` is a conditional group that is supported in Python 2.7.5 (probably works for higher versions but I don't know for previous ones). If there's `BACKUP`, it grabs all the non-spaces and if there's no `BACKUP`, it grabs everything till the end of the string.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/rD5wS4)

EDIT: As per comment, the regex that worked after @timmalos' modifications:

```
\#(?P<G>.*?[^E]BACKUP\s)?(?P<G2>f:\\\\Mailbox\\\)?(?P<jobFileList>(?(G)(?(G2)[^\]|\S)‌​*|.*))
```

Comment: As i have other cases i forgot and only one line each time i do the regex i use this one :
SomeText#(?:(.*?BACKUP) )?(?P<jobFileList>(?(1)[^ ]*|.*))
But still dont work ..

Comment: Sorry Jerry still dont manage to work after tests. Still on it

Comment: Ye i had a particular case . This one is working for me : \#(?P<G>.*?[^E]BACKUP\s)?(?P<G2>f:\\\\Mailbox\\\\)?(?P<jobFileList>(?(G)(?(G2)[^\\]|\S)*|.*))
but would be difficult to edit my post so i'll let it like that with your answer that works perfectly for the problem written.

Comment: @timmalos Oh okay, that's all right. I'll put it in my answer to make it more readable, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to match with a single regular expression however I know nothing of `splunk`. Maybe this will help:

```
("?[A-Z]:\\\\(?:".+|\S+)?)
```

Live demonstration [**here**](http://rubular.com/r/OTSa732MHq)